# crate alias IP on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-17.10

I need to create alias Ip for my local machine, as a reference I'm using https://websiteforstudents.com/switch-static-ip-address-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

ifconfig showing my network interface as:

```
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b7c0:76a:d0c0:3a7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6c:71:d9:21:ff:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 389087  bytes 342937114 (342.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 270723  bytes 54566302 (54.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but when I running `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` as mentioned in the reference I see different file content:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

so I make a try to add interface manually to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp

iface wlp3s0 inet static
address 10.254.254.254/24
```

but it's not working when I'm running `sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup wlp3s0` I'm getting:

```
ifdown: interface wlp3s0 not configured
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/6c:71:d9:21:ff:61
Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/6c:71:d9:21:ff:61
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4ec976a9)
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.106 from 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.1.106 -- renewal in 3106 seconds.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up wlp3s0.
```

I'm a novice in this, please help me to solve the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the alias must be of the form - wlp3sX:Y, where X is the physical network interface number and Y is the network interface number alias. everything is described in detail - http://drach.pro/blog/linux/item/71-ip-address-alias-on-centos-6-6   http://semenushkin.ru/2010/09/28/ifconfig-alias/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/585468/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-an-interface-in-ubuntu-14